# Twin paradox - a further variant

Tags: special-relativity, twin-paradox

I am still troubled by the "twin" paradox (thanks to those who have answered my previous question and suggested some reading which I will follow up). I have however thought of a variation on the experiment though - what if there are five clocks?

- Clock **1** is of an observer.
- Clocks **2** and **3** are travelling away from clock **1** at let's say 0.5 c in opposite directions.
- After one year (say from clock **1**'s perspective) they each encounter a clock (clock **4** and clock **5**) travelling towards clock **1** at 0.5 c (from clock one's perspective) and clock **4** and clock **5** synchronise their times to clock **2** and **3** respectively.

One year on the clocks **4** and **5** are passing clock **1**, and each other. What do each of the clocks show as the time ? In a sense clock **1** is not needed for this thought experiment but is still interesting to have it in the mix. But the basic issue is, will clocks **4** and **5** "see", each of them, the other clock as having run more slowly?

Comment: Do you understand about the [relativity of simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity)? It's really the key to all these kinds of questions. In the frame of clock 5, the event of clocks 2 and 4 passing one another and synchronizing happens much earlier than the event of clocks 3 and 5 passing and synchronizing, whereas in the frame of clock 4, the 3/5 synchronization happens much earlier than the 2/4 synchronization. Thus each one can believe the other is running slow, but still make sense of the fact that 4 and 5 read the same time when they meet.

Comment: @Hypnosifl that should probably be an answer

Answer (score 1):

If the incoming clocks pass the outgoing clocks *simultaneously* according to clock **1**, then this is an easy problem.

According to clock **1**, the event that clock **2** and clock **4** pass each other occurs when $$t_2 = \frac{1}{\gamma_{0.5}}\,\mathrm{yr} = 0.866\, \mathrm{yr}$$

Similarly for $t_3$.

Thus, at this event,

$$t_4 = 0.866\, \mathrm{yr}$$

Similarly for $t_5$.

One year later, the incoming clocks pass clock **1**.  At this event,

$$t_4 = 1.73 \, \mathrm{yr}$$

Similarly for $t_5$.

> But the basic issue is, will clocks 4 and 5 will each "see" the other
>   clock as having run more slowly?

Yes.  However, their times will agree at the event of passing clock **1**.  This is not a paradox.  According to either incoming clock, the meetings of the incoming and outgoing clocks on either side were **not** simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will see each other as both having the same time, which is less than the time of clock one.

In the coordinate system corresponding to clock 1, clocks 2 and 3 passed off times simultaneously.

In a coordinate system corresponding to a stationary clock 4, first clock 5 received some time from clock 3. In this frame clocks 3 and 4 are not dilated at all. Later, clock 4 received precisely the same time from clock 2, which had been heavily dilated. Clock 5 continues ticking at a dilated pace while clock 4 ticks at a normal pace, and by the time they've intersect everything is all caught up and they have the same times.

Draw a Minkowski diagram!

Answer (score 0):

There is **full symmetry** between what happens with the clocks in the pair **2** and **4**, and what happens with the clocks in the pair **3** and **5**. Thus, for simplicity of thinking, we can do the calculus of the 4D events of the pair **3**, **4**, from the point of view of the system of the clock **4**. For the other pair, and in the system of the clock **5** the calculus is identical. Thus, the readings of **4** and **5** when they pass by the Earth will be the same.

With respect to the clock on the Earth, the clocks **4** and **5** will show a shorter time because they copied the *local* time of **2** and **3** (the time in the system in which the clock is at rest), and then, until reaching the Earth, the clocks **4** and **5** measured also local time.